# Signs of Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that row operations do not preserve eigenvalues. However, do row operations preserve the sign of the real part of eigenvalues? (By row operations, I do not mean switching rows, just adding or subtracting a factor of one row to another).

I'm trying to figure out if I can triangularize a matrix and use the eigenvalues of the triangular matrix to say anything about the signs of the eigenvalues of the original matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can say anything how applying a row operation changes the sign of the eigenvalues, other than that the product of the signs must stay the same. For a two dimensional counterexample, consider

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2\\2 & 4\end{array}\right],$$
which has one zero and one positive eigenvalue (since the trace is positive). Subtracting three times the second row from the first gives
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}-5 & -10\\2 & 4\end{array}\right],$$
and since the trace is now negative, this matrix has one zero and one negative eigenvalue.

Comment: i see your point. thanks!

Comment: @liarose If you perform the same operations on the rows and on the columns, you're getting a [matrix congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) which does [preserve the inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia). Btw, I assume that your "thanks" means that the answer is useful to you, so an upvote (and/or accepting the answer) would be nice.

Comment: what do you mean by the same operations on the rows and on the columns? I cannot upvote. I do not have enough 'reputation'